# Violation of primary key constraint while update the database

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I try to update the database using Linq-to-SQL with this code:

```
    public Air_Score Update(Air_Score myApp)
    {
        Air_Score c = null;

        if (myApp != null)
        {
            c = e.Air_Score.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == myApp.ID);

            if (c != null)
            {
                c.Score = myApp.Score;
            }

            e.SaveChanges();
        }

        return c;
    }
```

When I call this function, I get this exception

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Air_Score'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Air_Score'. The duplicate key value is (222).

What's the error in the code ??

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in your error message. While updating data your table primary key is being repeated and it is 222. Check your table and maintain your function to avoid same value in primary key field. PRIMARY KEY must be unique.

Comment: i want to update the value of score for this id i don't want to insert another column

Comment: Can you post code of SaveChanges() function? I will give you exact solution.

Comment: it's in the metadata function that Saves all changes made in the context to the underlying database.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are creating a new Air_Score and copying an existing Air_Score and trying to save the context. So Entity framework considers it as an insert rather than an update. Try removing the initial declaration of the Air Score variable like below

```
  public Air_Score Update(Air_Score myApp)
    {

        if (myApp != null)
        {
            var c = e.Air_Score.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == myApp.ID);
            if (c != null)
            {
                c.Score = myApp.Score;

            }
            e.SaveChanges();
        }
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: i try this but it  isn't  the problem :(  i use this code in different solution and it work but in this not work i can't find the error